# How can I keep elements in different rows to have the same width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the div elements on first row (`deepskyblue` color) to align exactly below the div elements on second row (`deepskyblue` color), please provide me a solution how to align and the concept.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let arrayOfUrls = '{"https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started":"React Start",\
    "https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact/first-react-coc0845dcb1a26cb0769a2fea":"React training",\
    "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials":"Digital Ocean Tutorials",\
    "./page1.html":"NextPage",\
    "./img/flipcard.html":"Flipcard",\
    "./subscribe.html":"subscribe",\
    "./react.html":"React stuff",\
    "https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/common-beginner-mistakes/":"React Beginner mistakes",\
    "./futureuse.2html":"future use",\
    "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener":"event listeners"\
    }';

  const obj = JSON.parse(arrayOfUrls);

  for (let key in obj) {
    elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.setAttribute('id', obj[key]);
    console.log(elem);
    elem.innerHTML = `<a href=${key}>${obj[key]}</a>`;
    document.querySelector('.my_flexx').append(elem);
  }
});
```

```css
.my_flexx {
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 600px;
}

.my_flexx div {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="my_flexx"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to achieve is to always have 5 elements at the first row and 5 elements at the second row, where the width of elements on the top and bottom always have the same width, then you can use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) instead.

Flex is intended to be used to align along 1 axis / dimension only whereas Grid can be used to align across 2 axis / dimensions.

In the example below, I have used [`grid-template-columns` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) to make the top and bottom fit to at least the `min-width` of the child

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let arrayOfUrls =
    '{"https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started":"React Start",\
    "https://scrimba.com/learn/learnreact/first-react-coc0845dcb1a26cb0769a2fea":"React training",\
    "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials":"Digital Ocean Tutorials",\
    "./page1.html":"NextPage",\
    "./img/flipcard.html":"Flipcard",\
    "./subscribe.html":"subscribe",\
    "./react.html":"React stuff",\
    "https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/common-beginner-mistakes/":"React Beginner mistakes",\
    "./futureuse.2html":"future use",\
    "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener":"event listeners"\
    }';

  const obj = JSON.parse(arrayOfUrls);

  for (let key in obj) {
    elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.setAttribute('id', obj[key]);
    console.log(elem);
    elem.innerHTML = `<a href=${key}>${obj[key]}</a>`;
    document.querySelector('.my_flexx').append(elem);
  }
});
```

```css
.my_flexx {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  background-color: green;
  width: 600px;
}
.my_flexx div {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_flexx"></div>
```

Comment: suppose I had a 3rd row then going for grid would be better also? or flex or something else?

Comment: Hi @samreray, Yes you can use Grid for 3rd row as well. What I mean is Grid is good for 2 dimensions (rows **AND** columns) whereas Flex is only good for 1 dimension (rows **OR** columns). This means Grid can be used for any number of rows and columns.

Comment: works and accepted answer

Comment: Hi @samreray, glad to hear that it works for you. If you like the solution, you can consider accept the answer and/or upvote it, thank you!

Comment: suppose I had say 9 elements on a row then will I not need to punch `auto` 9 times like `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto ;` so instead of punching auto 9 times, so is there a alternate way then ?

Comment: @samreray, there's a [repeat() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) that you can utilize for that, updated my code snippet above with example